# Core Audio CAPlayThrough example with interface and guitar quality

Tags: objective-c, audio, core-audio

I'm playing around with the CoreAudio CAPlayThrough example provided by Apple. I'm not doing anything fancy, just attempting to get my guitar to pass through an audio interface (m-audio fast track pro) to my computer and then back out the interface into my headphones. I'm getting some audio to pass through, but the quality is terrible. I have the sample rate set to 48k on the input and output. Is there something I'm missing? I suspect it may be an issue with the bit rate, but I'm not sure how to change that. Any guesses as to what maybe causing this quality issue?